# Why is a validator lockout needed?

Tags: validator, consensus

I ran across the term "lockout" in the [Solana docs](https://solana.com/de/docs/terminology#lockout), defining it as

> The duration of time for which a validator is unable to vote on another fork.

Why does this exist and what purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 1):

solana validators have a tower file. Everytime a validator vote on a fork, the tower file keeps track of those votes and `lockout`.  A lockout occurs when a validator votes on a new block in a different fork than the one it previously voted on.

A `lockout` refers to the duration of time a validator is prevented from voting on a different fork. So the validators wont vote on different forks at the same time.

An attacker (In this case a validator) might try to spend the same digital asset twice by voting on conflicting forks, hoping to get one version accepted before the other. Validators on the Solana network track each other's votes. When a validator casts a vote on a particular block within a fork, this vote is recorded on the blockchain. If a validator attempts to vote on a block in a different fork after having already voted on a block in the current fork, this triggers a lockout. `Lockout` mechanism prevents malicious validators from immediately voting on the new fork, making it nearly impossible for an attacker to create and confirm a double-spending transaction on a conflicting fork within the short timeframe before the lockout expires.

Answer (score 0):

This is described in the solana documentation on [managing forks](https://docs.solanalabs.com/consensus/managing-forks#pruning-and-squashing).

Also, [this blog post](https://www.helius.dev/blog/consensus-on-solana#tower-bft-solana%E2%80%99s-consensus-mechanism) from helius explains it quite well.

Comment: Thank you! I read your links and got it. If you could copy out the relevant part from your links to your answer I'll upvote & accept your answer (asking so in case the links die at some point in the future this answer still makes sense).